# Error in executeSql query

Tags: jquery, html, database, cordova

I'm developing a cordova application where i need to create a login and a register.But i'm getting an error called "Error processing SQL: undefined" when running the application.I understand I'm getting this error because of the executeSql in insertUSERREG. But i have no idea why im getting this error.Please help.

html file:

```
 <form method="get" action="" onsubmit="return RegisteringUsers()">
        <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label for="username">Account User Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="User Name"/>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email"/>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Your Password" autocomplete="off"/>
         <input type="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

javascrpit file:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db ;
function onDeviceReady() {
     db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",2000000000);
    db.transaction(createDB, error1, successCB);
    window.localStorage.setItem("user","Not Logged In");
}

function createDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERSREG (db_name,db_una,db_email,db_password)');
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CARTORDER ');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CARTORDER (db_una, db_itemName, db_itemPrice , db_qty)');
}
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {

}  



 function RegisteringUsers(){   
 db.transaction(insertUSERREG, error2); 

 return false;
}  
 function insertUSERREG(tx){   
    var insertname = $('[name="name"]').val();
    var insertuna= $('[name="username"]').val();
    var insertemail= $('[name="email"]').val();
    var insertpassword= $('[name="password"]').val();           
    var sql='INSERT INTO USERSREG (db_name,db_una, db_email,db_password) VALUES (?, ?,?,?)';



     tx.executeSql(sql, [insertname ,insertuna,insertemail,insertpassword] ,SuccessqueryDB, errorCB);

 }
 function SuccessqueryDB(tx) {
    alert("Registered Sucessfully");
        $.mobile.changePage ("Home.html",{reverse: false,transition :"pop"});
} 
 function error2 () {
  alert("error2");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a few items that may have gone wrong:

1. tx is undefined
2. One of these: insertname, insertuna, insertemail, insertpassword is undefined.

You can use alert() and console.log to check the values of those.

Comment: I have tried with alert() for those variables and i got correct outputs.And i used console.log(tx); but im not getting any output for that.

Comment: Could you also try alert(err.message) in the errorCB? May be err.code is undefined for some reason.

Comment: Checked it and im getting "undefined"

Comment: Another suggestion - can you change the name of the database to something different: window.openDatabase("Database12345", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",2000000000);?

Comment: Then im getting the message "Registered Sucessfully" but after that im getting the error message error2 from RegisteringUsers() as well..

Comment: I haven't posted that part and i just added it by editing.Anyways im getting the error because of mobile.changePage. I replaced it with `window.location = "Home.html";` and its working perfectly.Thank you so much for your help :)